# Invoke function of AWS Lambda returns empty Payload using Go SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, localstack

Invoking an existing Lambda function (*previously created in zip form*) from within a Golang service which goes through fine. I can confirm in the logs. However the result coming from `Invoke()` function doesn't unmarshal into its struct representation which is an exact copy from the official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/lambda-go-example-run-function.html) and [example](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/go/example_code/lambda/aws-go-sdk-lambda-example-run-function.go) so printed output is always `{StatusCode:0 Headers:{ContentType:} Body:{Result: Data:[] Error:{Message:}}}`. I am wondering if I am missing something or there is an incompatibility between Localstack and AWS API. Any ideas please?

**ENVIRONMENT**

```sh
OS: MacOS
SDK/Tools: AWS SDK for Go v1.42.25 | Localstack:latest
CLI: v1.42.25 CLI: aws-cli/2.1.20 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/20.3.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off
```

**LAMBDA FUNCTION**

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type Request struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
}

type Response struct {
    OK bool  `json:"ok"`
    ID int64 `json:"id"`
}

func Create(ctx context.Context, req Request) (Response, error) {
    log.Printf("%+v\n", req)

    return Response{OK: true, ID: time.Now().UnixNano()}, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Create)
}
```

**Creating the function**

```sh
$ GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags "-s -w" -o main main.go
$ zip main.zip main
$ aws --profile localstack --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 \
      lambda create-function \
      --function-name create \
      --handler main \
      --zip-file fileb://main.zip \
      --runtime go1.x \
      --role create-role
```

```json
{
    "FunctionName": "create",
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:000000000000:function:create",
    "Runtime": "go1.x",
    "Role": "create-role",
    "Handler": "main",
    "CodeSize": 2379867,
    "Description": "",
    "Timeout": 3,
    "LastModified": "2021-12-30T11:54:04.603+0000",
    "CodeSha256": "NzeIzVXiCpXylWupilnJqyKRFcSohMjdQXp2sYHas2w=",
    "Version": "$LATEST",
    "VpcConfig": {},
    "TracingConfig": {
        "Mode": "PassThrough"
    },
    "RevisionId": "b6d6cd54-51a5-4790-843d-25e7bbda6aac",
    "State": "Active",
    "LastUpdateStatus": "Successful",
    "PackageType": "Zip"
}
```

**GO SERVICE**

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/lambda"
)

type CreateRequest struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
}

type CreateResponse struct {
    OK bool  `json:"ok"`
    ID int64 `json:"id"`
}

type getItemsResponseError struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

type getItemsResponseData struct {
    Item string `json:"item"`
}

type getItemsResponseBody struct {
    Result string                 `json:"result"`
    Data   []getItemsResponseData `json:"data"`
    Error  getItemsResponseError  `json:"error"`
}

type getItemsResponseHeaders struct {
    ContentType string `json:"Content-Type"`
}

type getItemsResponse struct {
    StatusCode int                     `json:"statusCode"`
    Headers    getItemsResponseHeaders `json:"headers"`
    Body       getItemsResponseBody    `json:"body"`
}

func main() {
    ses, err := session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
        Profile: "localstack",
        Config: aws.Config{
            Region:   aws.String("eu-west-1"),
            Endpoint: aws.String("http://localhost:4566"),
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    client := lambda.New(ses)

    request := CreateRequest{Username: "hello"}

    payload, err := json.Marshal(request)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    input := &lambda.InvokeInput{
        FunctionName: aws.String("create"),
        Payload:      payload,
    }

    result, err := client.Invoke(input)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result)

    var response getItemsResponse
    if err := json.Unmarshal(result.Payload, &response); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", response)
}
```

**Output**

```sh
$ go run main.go
{
  ExecutedVersion: "$LATEST",
  Payload: <sensitive>,
  StatusCode: 200
}
{StatusCode:0 Headers:{ContentType:} Body:{Result: Data:[] Error:{Message:}}}
```

**LOCALSTACK LOGS**

*Note:* This is same as what AWC Invoke CLI would give as well.

```sh
localstack    | 2021-12-30T11:58:12.851:DEBUG:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_executors: Lambda arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:000000000000:function:create result / log output:
localstack    | {"ok":true,"id":1640865492693728000}
localstack    | > START RequestId: 98684a77-743c-1749-369c-408cf18d5d79 Version: $LATEST
localstack    | > 2021/12/30 11:58:12 {Username:hello}
localstack    | > END RequestId: 98684a77-743c-1749-369c-408cf18d5d79
localstack    | > REPORT RequestId: 98684a77-743c-1749-369c-408cf18d5d79        Init Duration: 133.00 ms        Duration: 9.21 ms       Billed Duration: 10 ms  Memory Size: 1536 MB    Max Memory Used: 19 MB
```

```yaml
version: "2.1"

services:
  localstack:
    image: "localstack/localstack"
    container_name: "localstack"
    ports:
      - "4566-4599:4566-4599"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
      - SERVICES=lambda
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker
    volumes:
      - "/tmp/localstack:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

Comment: For `&lambda.InvokeInput`'s struct input, try adding another field called `InvocationType` with the value set to the string `"RequestResponse"` - does that change anything?

Comment: That's the default option anyway. Explicitly setting it won't change anything.

Comment: I'm aware although trying wouldn't hurt, would it?

Comment: As I said, explicitly setting it won't change anything so yes, no change in behaviour.

Comment: Also - try running both in AWS instead of using LocalStack. If it works, you can safely blame it on LocalStack and make this more defined.

Comment: Sadly I don't have an AWS account.

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile, if someone else faces the same issue I've found a temporary solution in order to get at least the response body. However I will still wait for an answer as to why the example in official doc won't work for the given setup although it is just a copy-paste.

Replace

```golang
var response getItemsResponse
```

with

```golang
var response map[string]interface{}
```

and get rid of all the un-exported structs.